# RouterChildActive Observable<boolean> for a component

Tags: angular, angular-router

We've got **AccountComponent** that contains some child links. We want to hide these child links whenever a child is active. Right now it seems we can achieve this in two ways:

**routerLinkActive and checking isActive on each of them to hide with CSS:**

```
<style>
  .content {
    &.child-active {
      .links {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  }
</style>

...

<div class="content" [class.child-active]="linkProfile?.isActive || linkSettings?.isActive">

  <div class="links">
    <a [routerLink]="['./profile']" routerLinkActive="active" #linkProfile="routerLinkActive">Profile</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['./settings']" routerLinkActive="active" #linkSettings="routerLinkActive">Settings</a>
  </div>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

**Hardcoding current parent route and checking it's exactly active:**

```
@Component({ ... })
export class AccountComponent {
  isParentActive$ = this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter((event): event is NavigationEnd => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(() => this.router.isActive('/account', true)),
    );
}

...

<div class="content">

  <div class="links" *ngIf="isParentActive$ | async === false">
    <a [routerLink]="['./profile']">Profile</a>
    <a [routerLink]="['./settings']">Settings</a>
  </div>

  <router-outlet></router-outlet>

</div>
```

The CSS way to me is quite hacky for obvious reasons and the Parent hardcoding an absolute route to check for exact equality can't be re-used when the path to it changes.

Is it possible to do this any better way or should an issue be created to improve the Router API within Angular?

Answer (score 0):

In documentation you have something like this:

```
<div routerLinkActive="active-link" [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{exact: true}">
  <a routerLink="/user/jim">Jim</a>
  <a routerLink="/user/bob">Bob</a>
</div>
```

This will set the active-link class on the div tag if the url is either '/user/jim' or '/user/bob'.

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

or you can try like this, if you want to remove it completely (need to test it not totally sure if it works)

```
<div ngIf="stuff.isActive" routerLinkActive="active-link" #stuff="routerLinkActive">
   <a routerLink="/user/jim">Jim</a>
   <a routerLink="/user/bob">Bob</a>
</div>
```

you can also try to simplify it (if there is no ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush):

```
<div *ngIf="router.isActive('/account', true))">...</div>
```